# How do you install icon themes and use them? (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: themes

I am a newbie to Ubuntu and I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my HP Stream 14 Laptop yesterday and I am trying to get the hang of it.

The certain theme I am trying  to install is McMuse icon theme (https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1348081/)

Answer (score 8):

Once you downloaded the above Icon theme you mentioned.

Extract it, Copy the two folders and place them in `$HOME/.icons` directory. Create the directory if it does not exist.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Install `gnome-tweaks` with below command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

and select the icon theme you wish.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I paste the command into the terminal, it says Unable to locate package gnome-tweaks

Comment: Ok.. `sudo apt update` once updated.. then `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: @Jatatao I'm happy to know that this answer worked for you. You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the complete tutorial. :)